# How to restart a Windows VM using chef

Tags: powershell, knife, chef-infra, chef-windows

My requirement is to restart the windows vm after the software gets installed, I am automating the entire process using chef. Is there any method for doing that?

Can we do through power shell ?
Is there any method for chef to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [windows](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/windows) cookbook offers a [reboot](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows#windows_reboot) resource.

Comment: when i am using the reboot resource , the VM is actually not getting restarted , and i am getting the following error                 ERROR: WinRM::WinRMHTTPTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server (500)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above check out the links [windows cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/windows) & [windows reboot](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows#windows_reboot). All my info is gathered from the previous links.

Include the WindowsRebootHandler in the recipe

```
include_recipe 'windows::reboot_handler'
```

Create a reboot block

```
windows_reboot 30 do
  timeout 30
  reason 'Restarting computer in 30 seconds!'
  action :nothing
end
```

- timeout: timeout delay in seconds before rebooting. default is 60 seconds
- reason: reason for the reboot. default is 'Opscode Chef initiated reboot'

Notify the reboot block to trigger the reboot

```
notifies :request, 'windows_reboot[30]', :delayed
```

- :delayed - notification is queued up and executed at the very end of a chef-client run
- :immediately - notification is ran immediately

Comment: when i am using the reboot resource , the VM is actually not getting restarted , and i am getting the following error                                

ERROR: WinRM::WinRMHTTPTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server (500)

Comment: Seems like WinRM isn't setup properly on the target server but hard to tell without knowing the Chef commands you are using. I have explained Windows Chef bootstrap previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813486/unable-to-bootstrap-chef-on-windows/23919580#23919580).